# Lock statement vs Monitor.Enter method

Tags: c#, command-line-interface, garbage-collection

I suppose that this is an interesting code example.

We have a class -- let's call it **Test** -- with a **Finalize** method. In the **Main** method there are two code blocks where I am using a lock statement and a **Monitor.Enter()** call. Also, I have two instances of the **Test** class here.
The experiment is pretty simple:  Null the **Test** variable within locking block and then try to collect it manually with the **GC.Collect** method call.
So, to see the **Finalize** call I am calling the **GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers** method. Everything is very simple, as you can see.

By the definition of the **lock** statement, it's opened by the compiler to the **try**{...}**finally**{..} block, with a **Monitor.Enter** call inside of the **try** block and **Monitor**. Then it exits in the **finally** block. I've tried to implement the **try-finally** block manually.

I've expected the same behaviour in both cases -- that of using lock and that of using **Monitor.Enter**. But, surprise, surprise it is different, as you can see below:

```
public class Test
{
    private string name;

    public Test(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Finalizing class name {0}.", name));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test1 = new Test("Test1");
        var test2 = new Test("Tesst2");
        lock (test1)
        {
            test1 = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Manual collect 1.");
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Console.WriteLine("Manual collect 2.");
            GC.Collect();
        }

        var lockTaken = false;
        System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(test2, ref lockTaken);
        try {
            test2 = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Manual collect 3.");
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Console.WriteLine("Manual collect 4.");
            GC.Collect();
        }
        finally {
           System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(test2);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The output of this example is:

> Manual collect 1. Manual collect 2.
>   Manual collect 3. Finalizing class
>   name Test2. Manual collect 4.
>   And null reference exception in last finally block because test2 is null reference.

I was surprised and disassembled my code into IL. So, here is the IL dump of **Main** method:

```
.entrypoint
.maxstack 2
.locals init (
    [0] class ConsoleApplication2.Test test1,
    [1] class ConsoleApplication2.Test test2,
    [2] bool lockTaken,
    [3] bool <>s__LockTaken0,
    [4] class ConsoleApplication2.Test CS$2$0000,
    [5] bool CS$4$0001)
L_0000: nop 
L_0001: ldstr "Test1"
L_0006: newobj instance void ConsoleApplication2.Test::.ctor(string)
L_000b: stloc.0 
L_000c: ldstr "Tesst2"
L_0011: newobj instance void ConsoleApplication2.Test::.ctor(string)
L_0016: stloc.1 
L_0017: ldc.i4.0 
L_0018: stloc.3 
L_0019: ldloc.0 
L_001a: dup 
L_001b: stloc.s CS$2$0000
L_001d: ldloca.s <>s__LockTaken0
L_001f: call void [mscorlib]System.Threading.Monitor::Enter(object, bool&)
L_0024: nop 
L_0025: nop 
L_0026: ldnull 
L_0027: stloc.0 
L_0028: ldstr "Manual collect."
L_002d: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
L_0032: nop 
L_0033: call void [mscorlib]System.GC::Collect()
L_0038: nop 
L_0039: call void [mscorlib]System.GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
L_003e: nop 
L_003f: ldstr "Manual collect."
L_0044: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
L_0049: nop 
L_004a: call void [mscorlib]System.GC::Collect()
L_004f: nop 
L_0050: nop 
L_0051: leave.s L_0066
L_0053: ldloc.3 
L_0054: ldc.i4.0 
L_0055: ceq 
L_0057: stloc.s CS$4$0001
L_0059: ldloc.s CS$4$0001
L_005b: brtrue.s L_0065
L_005d: ldloc.s CS$2$0000
L_005f: call void [mscorlib]System.Threading.Monitor::Exit(object)
L_0064: nop 
L_0065: endfinally 
L_0066: nop 
L_0067: ldc.i4.0 
L_0068: stloc.2 
L_0069: ldloc.1 
L_006a: ldloca.s lockTaken
L_006c: call void [mscorlib]System.Threading.Monitor::Enter(object, bool&)
L_0071: nop 
L_0072: nop 
L_0073: ldnull 
L_0074: stloc.1 
L_0075: ldstr "Manual collect."
L_007a: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
L_007f: nop 
L_0080: call void [mscorlib]System.GC::Collect()
L_0085: nop 
L_0086: call void [mscorlib]System.GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
L_008b: nop 
L_008c: ldstr "Manual collect."
L_0091: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
L_0096: nop 
L_0097: call void [mscorlib]System.GC::Collect()
L_009c: nop 
L_009d: nop 
L_009e: leave.s L_00aa
L_00a0: nop 
L_00a1: ldloc.1 
L_00a2: call void [mscorlib]System.Threading.Monitor::Exit(object)
L_00a7: nop 
L_00a8: nop 
L_00a9: endfinally 
L_00aa: nop 
L_00ab: call string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
L_00b0: pop 
L_00b1: ret 
.try L_0019 to L_0053 finally handler L_0053 to L_0066
.try L_0072 to L_00a0 finally handler L_00a0 to L_00aa
```

I don't see any difference between the **lock** statement and the **Monitor.Enter** call. 
So, why do I still have a reference to the instance of **test1** in the case of **lock**, and the object is not collected by GC, but in the case of using **Monitor.Enter** it is collected and finalized?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is because the reference pointed to by `test1` is assigned to the local variable `CS$2$0000` in the IL code. You null out the `test1` variable in C#, but the `lock` construct gets compiled in such a manner that a separate reference is maintained.

It is actually quite clever that the C# compiler does this. Otherwise it would be possible to circumvent the guarentee the `lock` statement is supposed to enforce of releasing the lock upon exiting the critical section.

Answer (score 83):

> I do not see any difference between lock statement and Monitor.Enter call.

Look more carefully. The first case copies the reference to a second local variable to ensure that it stays alive.

Notice what the C# 3.0 spec says on the subject:

> A lock statement of the form "lock (x) ..." where x is an expression of a reference-type, is precisely equivalent to

```
System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(x);
try { ... }
finally { System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(x); }
```

> except that x is only evaluated once.

It's that last bit -- **except that x is only evaluated once** -- that is the key to the behaviour. In order to ensure that x is evaluated only once we evaluate it once, store the result in a local variable, and re-use that local variable later.

In C# 4 we've changed the codegen so that it is now

```
bool entered = false;
try { 
  System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(x, ref entered);
  ... 
}
finally { if (entered) System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(x); }
```

but again, x is only **evaluated** once. In your program you are evaluating the lock expression *twice*. Your code really should be

```
    bool lockTaken = false;   
    var temp = test2;
    try {   
        System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(temp, ref lockTaken);   
        test2 = null;   
        Console.WriteLine("Manual collect 3.");   
        GC.Collect();   
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();   
        Console.WriteLine("Manual collect 4.");   
        GC.Collect();   
    }   
    finally {   
       System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(temp);   
    }
```

Now is it clear why this works the way it does?

(Also note that in C# 4 the Enter is *inside* the try, not outside as it was in C# 3.)

Comment: Why did you decide to move it inside the try in 4.0?

Comment: @Brian: Read http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/08/17/subtleties-of-c-il-codegen.aspx and then  http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx

Comment: Yep, it is clear now, and it is my bad i did not saw the difference myself. Thanks for explanaiton.

Comment: I wonder if .net will ever provide an equivalent for the creation of IDisposable objects (e.g. have the object under construction store itself in a byref parameter, so that if the constructor throws an exception the partially-constructed object can be Disposed (naturally, the Dispose would have to be aware that the object might not be fully constructed, but in many cases that shouldn't be too hard).