# How is the critical section associated with every Object initialized?

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, critical-section

When you say

```
lock (obj)
    ...
```

.NET uses the critical section in `obj` to synchronize the following statements.

How is this critical section initialized? (e.g. is it initialized at construction time, or lazily?)

Comment: What makes you think there's a critical section in the object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lock (Monitor) internal implementation in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111779/lock-monitor-internal-implementation-in-net)

Comment: @JimMischel Its similar, but has a different focus than that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every object gets a 4 byte "block" of memory allocated to it (the syncblk) that is an index into a SyncTableEntry.  When the object is created, the syncblk is assigned 0, which prevents any extra memory allocation (other than this 4 byte number).  When a lock is taken, this syncblk is set to the appropriate entry in the table, which may then cause an allocation.  In effect, it's a lazy initialization.

When you call lock(object), this is effectively using `Monitor.Enter` on the object, which in turn sets the entry appropriately.  For details, see this [MSDN article on .NET Memory Internals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S7).

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's documentation the process allocates the memory of a critical section when a variable of type CRITICAL_SECTION is declared.