# Lock code sections with languages that don't support multi-threading

Tags: multithreading, locking

In some cases we need to be sure that some section of code won't be used by one thread while another thread is in this section. Using languages that support multi-threading it's easy to achieve with "locking" these parts. But when we have to "simulate" threads there's not built-in thing like `lock` keyword in C# or `Lock` interface in Java. The best way I've found to lock sections in these cases look likes this:

```
if (!locked){
    locked = true;

    do some stuff

    locked = false;
} else {
    add to queue
}
```

What are the drawbacks of current solution? Does it worth to actively use one?

Comment: Small point - unless you have code that modifies itself, code never needs locking.  What may need protection by lock is the data accessed by that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe two threads can enter in the `if` statement.

**Explanation**

If `T1` entered in the `if` statement and doesn't change the `locked` value. Suddenly, if the CPU change `T1` for `T2`, `locked` value will continue `false`. Then `T2` will enter into `if` statement too.

```
T1 -> !locked   -> Stopped -> Waiting -> ... //locked value still false and T2
T2 ->  Waiting  ->  Waked  -> !locked -> ... //will be able to enter into if
```

You should take a look at [**Semaphores**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) and [**Mutexes**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) and If you will only use two process you can use the [**Peterson's Algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm), but it still have a busy wait to deal!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) and syncronization primitives provided by underlaying system or OS: mutex, semaphore, motinore, etc. You'll be suprised that even C++ does not have `Lock` keyword, but everything is fine. C# `lock` is implemented using [monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) and you could find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111779/lock-monitor-internal-implementation-in-net).