# Why is semaphore not released when given cancellationToken is cancelled

Tags: c#, .net, semaphore

`SemaphoreSlim` has a `WaitAsync()` method that takes a `CancellationToken`.  I'd expect the semaphore to get released when that token is cancelled, but this doesn't seem to be the case.  Consider the code below:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
// CurrentCount is 1
await semaphore.WaitAsync(tokenSource.Token);
// CurrentCount is 0 as we'd expect

tokenSource.Cancel(); // Token is cancelled

for(var i = 0; i< 10; i++)
{
    var c = semaphore.CurrentCount; // Current count remains 0, even though token was cancelled
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Even after the token gets cancelled, the `CurrentCount` remains at 0.  I'm guessing this is by design, but what exactly is the `CancellationToken` used for if not to release the semaphore when the token is cancelled?  Thanks!

Comment: ````CancellationToken```` used for cancelling the wait. Has no business with the acquired semaphore. In your code when you call ````WaitAsync```` it returns immediately as you noticed because 1 thread was allowed to have the semaphore. If you init the semaphore with 0 current allowed threads then the wait call will really wait. Now if you call ````tokenSource.Cancel()```` on other thread then the wait returns because it monitors your token during wait for semaphore.

Comment: @cly Oh, that makes perfect sense!  Thanks so much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background**

[SemaphoreSlim Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624497/does-semaphoreslims-timeout-defeat-its-own-purpose)

> Represents a lightweight alternative to Semaphore that limits the
> number of threads that can access a resource or pool of resources
> concurrently.
>
> ...
>
> The count is decremented each time a thread enters the semaphore, and
> incremented each time a thread releases the semaphore. To enter the
> semaphore, a thread calls one of the Wait or WaitAsync overloads. To
> release the semaphore, it calls one of the Release overloads. When the
> count reaches zero, subsequent calls to one of the Wait methods block
> until other threads release the semaphore. If multiple threads are
> blocked, there is no guaranteed order, such as FIFO or LIFO, that
> controls when threads enter the semaphore.

[SemaphoreSlim.CurrentCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.currentcount?view=net-5.0)

> Gets the number of remaining threads that can enter the SemaphoreSlim
> object.
>
> ...
>
> The initial value of the CurrentCount property is set by the call to
> the SemaphoreSlim class constructor. It is decremented by each call to
> the Wait or WaitAsync method, and incremented by each call to the
> Release method.

That's to say, every time you enter a semaphore you reduce the remaining threads that can enter. If you have entered successfully, the count is decremented.

Calling the *CancellationToken* that is being awaited only has an effect on threads awaiting the `WaitAsync`, or if you try to await the token again.

To answer the question, the *CancellationToken* is solely for the awaiting `WaitAsync`, it has no affect on how many threads can enter the `SemaphoreSlim`.

**Furthermore**

I think the real and pertinent question is, do you need to release a `SemephoreSlim` that has been cancelled! and the answer is no. An awaiting `SemephoreSlim` has not successfully entered or affected the count anyway, it's awaiting because there are no threads permissible.

And lastly, do you need release a `SemephoreSlim` that has been timed out via the timeout overload. The answer to that is, this method returns a `bool` as to whether it was entered successfully, that return value needs to be checked to determined whether it may need to be released.

**Fun fact**

This is the exact reason why you don't put the wait inside a try finally pattern that releases the slim.

```
// this can throw, or timeout
var result = await semaphore.WaitAsync(someTimeOut, tokenSource.Token);

if(!result)
  return;

try
{
   // synchronized work here
}
finally
{
   semaphore.Release();
}
```

Releasing inappropriately will cause all sorts of problems and result in another exception sooner or later because you are exceeding the maximum count.