# Issue when using Monitor with locktaken overload in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, monitor

I was testing Monitor with lock taken overload as following.

```
public static void Enter(object obj, ref bool lockTaken);
```

I have created following sample for this however not sure what's the easy fix.

```
class TestMonitor
    {
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        private static object myLock = new object();
        bool isLockTaken = false;
        public void DoDivide()
        {
            try
            {
                Monitor.Enter(myLock, ref isLockTaken); //t2 fails here.
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        num1 = rnd.Next(1, 5);
                        num2 = rnd.Next(1, 5);
                        Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
                        num1 = 0;
                        num2 = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (isLockTaken)  { Monitor.Exit(myLock); }
            }
         }
    }

 class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Monitor Demo";
            TestMonitor testThreadSafe = new TestMonitor();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(testThreadSafe.DoDivide);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(testThreadSafe.DoDivide);            
            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();  
        }
    }
```

I am getting error when 2nd thread (t2) try to access `Monitor.Enter(myLock, ref isLockTaken);` where it find that isLockTaken is true although it expects isLockTaken as false. isLockTaken is true made by 1st thread (t1) because it has obtained the lock. I kind of understood the issue but can someone points me towards easy fix so that both thread can work without issues.

Comment: Thnx Gediminas Masaitis for the response. I know we can use lock keyword which automatically handles. However I was trying to play with Monitor overload.

Comment: I just tested that when I put bool isLockTaken = false; inside DoDivide, it works without any issue. However will look for some other comments if I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy fix would be to not use the `isLockTaken` boolean at all:

```
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(myLock);
    // ...
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(myLock);
}
```

Or even better, to use a [`lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) statement:

```
lock(myLock)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

However if you want to use the overload with `ref bool lockTaken`, the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> The input must be false.

The simple way to do this would be to move your `isLockTaken` field into a local method variable. Then, since each thread gets it's own stack, it would get it's own copy of the `isLockTaken` variable.

```
bool isLockTaken = false;
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(myLock, ref isLockTaken);
    // ...
}
finally
{
    if(isLockTaken)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(myLock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx Gediminas Masaitis. It fixes the issue.

Comment: +1 for lock(myLock), as it's probably better and easier to understand depending on the situation. Read more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837070/lock-statement-vs-monitor-enter-method

Answer (score 2):

From Microsoft documentation:

> lockTaken
>   Type: System.Boolean
>
> The result of the attempt to acquire the lock, passed by reference.
>   **The input must be false.** The **output is true if the lock is acquired**;
>   otherwise, the output is false. The output is set even if an exception
>   occurs during the attempt to acquire the lock.

Since you're declaring isLockTaken in the class, it'll become true and keep being true. It should go into the dodivide function.

Comment: Thnx Crypth. It fixes the issue.

Comment: Please remember to set a correct answer as an answer, not only up voting.